# Issue using multiple params in spring-aop

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

So, I am working with Spring boot aop

used `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'` in build.gradle

Issue:
I added `@LogMetrics` annotation in following functions

```
    @LogMetrics
    public Employee createEmployee(String name, String empId)

    @LogMetrics
    public Employee oneparam(String a) {}

    @LogMetrics
    public Employee twoparam(String a, String b) {}

    @LogMetrics
    public Employee threeparam(String a, String b, String c) {}
```

but advice is not printing as per my requirement. It is only printing for createEmployee function

I used

```
@Before(value = "@annotation(com.paradox.springsample.annotations.LogMetrics) || within(com.paradox.springsample.annotations.LogMetrics)")
```

Can someone help me explain why the logs are not getting printed for above functions ?
Is something wrong in my code or any implementation detail i am missing out
Intellij was able to detect advice methods though

curl used::
`curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9000/employee/add?name=rajat&empId=123'`

Github url for code: https://github.com/rajat19/spring-aop-issue
You can clone the repo and test it out.
I can explain more on this if someone wants to test and check

Things I tried-

1. adding `args(a, b)` etc. to distinguish functions inside @Before
2. making return type same for all functions
3. using `execution(* com.paradox.springsample.services.EmployeeService.*(..))`

Comment: Short version of my answer I linked to when closing this question as a duplicate: Either use native AspectJ and avoid Spring AOP's dynamic proxies or auto-wire the proxy into the class (ugly, but easy and working): `@Autowired EmployeeService INSTANCE;` and then `Employee a = INSTANCE.oneparam("");` etc.

Comment: @kriegaex thanks for your help. Let me test it out the changes you suggested